# C programming fwrite jumps to end of file

Tags: c++, c, fwrite, fseek, ftell

I'm writing a C module and I'm running into an interesting problem I never seen before.

```
// Many other operations before this point
fseek(samples_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
printf("ftell A1 %llu\n", ftell(samples_file));
count = fwrite(channel_buffer+chan_type.size*set_index, 1, chan_type.size, samples_file);
printf("count %llu\n", count);
printf("ftell A2 %llu\n", ftell(samples_file));
// Many more operations to come after this point
```

When I run the module, I get a printout like the following:

```
ftell A1 0
count 8
ftell A2 6018
```

I have set the file pointer to the very start of the file. When I write some data, it should write the data out at the position I seek'd to and then increment the file position with the number of bytes written (in this case, 8). However, when I do an ftell, it seems that the position suddenly jumped to 6018 (which happens to be the original size of the file plus 8).

Why does this occur and how do I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like the file has been opened in append mode. Check that there's no `"a"` in the second argument to `fopen()`.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. Is there a way I can open the file in read-write mode _without_ overwriting the file (IE, the original contents remain) like append mode. However, unlike append mode will not have the behavior I'm seeing now?

Comment: You are looking for `"r+"`. Take a look at the manual pages or a good C book -- all valid modes would be spelled out there.